# Need help returning duplicates from a join onto a single line with a sum function included

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin, sum

I have two tables t1 and t2. t1 contains some message data i have set up to be searched against t2 which contains a list of keywords all with their own individual score. Now I have been moderately successful with this and have managed to return all rows in t1 that contain any keyword within t2 with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.RowID, t1.ChatNo, t1.UserNo, 
t1.Chat, t2.Keywords, SUM(t2.KeywordScore) AS Score
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Chat LIKE CONCAT('%', + t2.Keywords , + '%')
WHERE t2.Keywords IS NOT NULL OR t1.ChatNo > 0 AND t1.UserNo > 0
GROUP BY t1.RowID, t2.Keywords
```

Now my issue is, it returns duplicate results if a chat message has multiple keywords and on each duplicate row it will have picked up a different keyword and that keywords score. Now because of this I believe my query is attempting to sum the rows individually so cannot total them up (correct me if i am wrong).
for example:

```
RowID  ChatNo  UserNO         Chat        Keywords   Score

  1      1       1     "...ex1 ex2 ex3"     ex1        2
  1      1       1     "...ex1 ex2 ex3"     ex2        4
  1      1       1     "...ex1 ex2 ex3"     ex3        1
```

Now what I would like it to do is to return all the keywords found in a message on a single line (or list) and still be able to SUM up the values of the keywords found within the message and display the total, like so:

```
RowID  ChatNo  UserNO         Chat          Keywords      Score

  1      1       1     "...ex1 ex2 ex3"   ex1, ex2, ex3     7
```

I have done some searching and testing haven't really come across a solution that has worked for me. So if anyone can give me some assistance on how I might proceed and get the query to output the results on a single line with a the score summed up it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GROUP_CONCAT()

Also `distinct` doesn't seem necessary so I deleted it.

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.RowID, t1.ChatNo, t1.UserNo, 
t1.Chat, group_concat(t2.Keywords, ', '), SUM(t2.KeywordScore) AS Score
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Chat LIKE CONCAT('%', + t2.Keywords , + '%')
WHERE t2.Keywords IS NOT NULL OR t1.ChatNo > 0 AND t1.UserNo > 0
GROUP BY t1.RowID, t1.ChatNo, t1.UserNo, t1.Chat
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It just needed a SEPARATOR in the group_concat section in the SELECT.